# save trained model of Spark's Naive Bayes classificator

Tags: java-8, apache-spark

Somebody knows - is it possible to save trained model of Spark's Naive Bayes classificator (for example in text file), and load it in future if required?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you using MlLib ? Maybe you could save the weights of the trained model and save them. Then when required, create a new model, giving these weights as initial weights ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MLib. Is it possible to get weights from training model?

Comment: yes. I use LogisticRegressionModel. then model.weights() gives the weight vector. was planning to use it like this. Couldn't find any other option other than serializing the whole model.

Comment: Thanks Man! I'll follow your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried saving and loading the model. I was not able to recreate the model using the stored weights. ( Couldn't find the proper constructor ). But the whole model is serializable. So you can store and load it as follows :

store as :

```
val fos = new FileOutputStream(<storage path>)   
val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)
oos.writeObject(model)     
oos.close
```

and load it in:

```
val fos = new FileInputStream(<storage path>)
val oos = new ObjectInputStream(fos)
val newModel = oos.readObject().asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel]
```

It worked for me

it is discussed in this thread :
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-save-mllib-model-to-hdfs-and-reload-it-td11953.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in functions (Spark version 2.1.0). Use [`NaiveBayesModel#save`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/NaiveBayesModel.html#save(org.apache.spark.SparkContext,%20java.lang.String)) in order to store the model and [`NaiveBayesModel#load`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/NaiveBayesModel.html#load(org.apache.spark.SparkContext,%20java.lang.String)) in order to read previously stored model.

Method `save` comes from [`Saveable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/Saveable.html#save(org.apache.spark.SparkContext,%20java.lang.String)) and is implemented by wide range of classification models. Method `load` seems to be static in each classification model implementation.